# How to specify platform on selenium/node-chorme image

Tags: kubernetes, selenium-webdriver

I am running selenium grid in kubernetes. Running one hub and one chrome-node. I am using deployment file from [https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/blob/master/staging/selenium/selenium-node-chrome-deployment.yaml`](https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/blob/master/staging/selenium/selenium-node-chrome-deployment.yaml%60). the image used is
containers:
- name: selenium-node-chrome
image: selenium/node-chrome:4.0
If you will run above setup, a chrome node will be created, have platform: linux.
I want to run a chrome-node with windows zip. Is there a way we can provide node image something like: selenium/node-chrome:4.0-windows ?? Or some other option?